# Configure iReport with BigQuery

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport, google-bigquery

I am trying to configure iReport from [Jaspersoft](http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/ireport-designer) with [BigQuery](https://code.google.com/p/starschema-bigquery-jdbc/) and I am following every step posted on the Internet but they don't work.

The specific steps to configure this are following those from [here](https://code.google.com/p/starschema-bigquery-jdbc/wiki/JasperReports#Connection_steps_for_creating_reports)

The main step is to create a Project in BigQuery which gives you 3 main things:

- the Project ID
- the Client ID
- the Client Secret

With these parameters you can create the `JDBC URL` explained [here](https://code.google.com/p/starschema-bigquery-jdbc/wiki/JDBCURL) which is required to connect iReport with BigQuery.

BUT, when you get to the part when you only have to put the Credentials (username, and password) on the "New Database JDBC Connection" creation of iReport, I can't use my `Client Secret`, iReport requests the `<path to key file>`, which I think is a `*.p12` file, because iReport gives this error:

`QL problems: java.io.IOException: toDerInputStream rejects tag type ##`

Please help either on creating this `*.p12` file and see what happens or maybe giving me the exact steps to make this configuration work, if any of you have configured this correctly.

Thank You.

Comment: You should give a try to iNet Designer, there's a free edition out there, I'd like it more than jasper.

Comment: I'll try it, but for this project I need to use Jaspersoft.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *.p12 file is used when you want to connect with a ServiceAccount.

Please go to [Google apis console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/b/0/) and select your project.

At the Dashboard there will be your ***Project ID***

To obtain ***username***, and ***password*** please go to the API Access menu and select: ***Create another client ID*** From here you either select *service account* or *Installed application*.

If you choose *service account* you'll get the .p12 file and the username.

If you choose *installed application* then you should select the *Other* then press **Create Client ID** then you have your **client ID** and **client Secret**

Hopefully this will solve your problem, if not, then feel free to ask.

Comment: Perfect, I was using it like a installed app, so I didn't received the .p12 file. but just used the *service account* option and yes, It works. Thank you!

Comment: Oops Now I got one more problem, the .p12 file needs a password to use it. And how do I tell the iReport to use that password for the queries?, maybe adding a parameter to the JDBC URL or how?

Comment: My mistake, I didn't use the correct username, it was the client email.